# Method to return an array

Tags: android, arrays, class, methods, call

In my android project, I have a countdown that randomizes a boolean for an array. The problem is, every time it ticks it always creates the array and the for loop. Can someone help me how to import my codes on a seperate class and method? I just want to call the returned value of an array in my countdown while it loops on a separate class. Please help me, TIA! :)

This is my countdown inside my onCreate():

```
new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {
  public void onTick(long msUntilFinished) {
    txtCounter.setText("" + msUntilFinished/1000);
    ImageView[] pic= {img1, img2, img3, img4, img5};
    Random aRandom = new Random();

    for (int i=0;i<12;i++){
      arrays[i] = aRandom.nextBoolean();

      if(arrays[i]){
        pic[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.show);
        appear = true;
      } else {
        pic[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.hide);
        appear = false;
      }
    }
  } // end of onTick

  public void onFinish() {
    txtCounter.setText("done!");
  }
}.start();
```

Comment: Are you talking about calling functions from another class that return a value or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.. I'm planning to put my arrays in a separate function of a class and will call its index by the countdown method using for loop. I'm still not familiar in method calls and hoping to learn here.. BTW, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the array to be created each time it ticks just place the array initialization outside of the thread like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<12;i++){ arrays[i] = aRandom.nextBoolean();}
new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000)
{
...
}.start();
```

Important: "arrays" has to be final. If you cannot do this then you have to do:

```
for (int i=0;i<12;i++){ arrays[i] = aRandom.nextBoolean();}
final SomeClass[] finalArray = arrays;
new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000)
{
...
 if(finalArray[i]) ...
...
}.start();
```

Comment: Thank you very much kirdie! Will try that ASAP!:)

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the answer as correct if it works and upvote if you think it deserves it :-)

Comment: One more thing, I want my array to be accessible in all my methods.. Where will I put it, below the class? Should I still use final? I have a onClick() method. I want it also to loop my array.

Comment: Yes, you should place it below the class. If you still need to use final depends on if you will change the variable to point to another array or not. My recommendation would be to make it final first and if you get an error with it use my second suggested code. P.S.: Please upvote the answers that were helpful to you and accept the answer if it is correct :-)

Comment: I'm still new here and doesn't have enough pts to vote up.. I'll vote it up later if I have enough pts.. BTW, thanks very much sir! Your a great help! :)